# Dynamic object creation in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have three data sources and a web config setting. Initially I select data source according to web config setting but in case this data source return null or 0 value, then I need to create 2 data source class object and try to get data and so on for 3 data source as well. 
Till now I use Factory pattern to select data source class object, Is there any better solution for it to switch data source object at run time till no data found.

```
Class DataSource{
....
....
public static IDatasource GetObjectDAL()
{
string DataMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSource"];
switch(DataMode)
{
case "DBSource1":
{ return new Source1();
}
case "DBSource2":
{
 return new Source2();
}
case "DBSource3":
{
return new Source3();
}
default:
{
return new Source1();
}
}}
```

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42133/design-pattern-for-implementing-multiple-data-sources

Comment: You should post some code which demonstrates what you want to achieve. Apart from this your question is fairly opinion-based and unspecific, as "better way" implies you´re unsatisfied with what you already have. However we don´t know why you think so. So how should we know what you consider "better"?

Comment: Ok. I tried. thanks